# Use the joint p.d.f. to calculate $ P(X+Y<2)$

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $f(x,y) = \frac 3{16}xy^2~\Big[0 \lt x \lt 2, 0 \lt y \lt 2\Big]$, be the joint p.d.f. of $X$ and $Y$. Use the joint p.d.f. to calculate $P(X+Y\lt 2)$.

I'm again confused on how to set up the limits of integration. I know how to calculate the double integral, but I always get confused on what the limits for the integrals should be. I did this: $X + Y \lt 2 ~\equiv~ X \lt Y - 2$. I just don't know where to put that, and how to incorporate the $ 0 \lt x \lt 2$, and $0 \lt y \lt 2$, with the $X + Y \lt 2$. This should be easy, but it's really confusing me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Uh, $X+Y<2 \equiv X<2-Y$.

Comment: Yeah, sorry that was a typo, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find $$\iint\limits_{\substack{0<x<2,\\ 0<y<2,\\ x+y<2}} f(x,y)\operatorname d (x,y) = \int_0^2\int_0^{2-x} \tfrac 3{16} xy^2\operatorname d y\operatorname d x$$

Basically be cause $0<x<2, 0<y<2,$ and $y<2-x$ then $0<y<2-x<2$

We want to integrate over the region where the three criteria are met: those of the supports and the favoured event. $0<x<2, 0<y<2,$ and $y<2-x$

For the inner integral we select one variable and integrate over the range it can take with respect to the other. In this case $0<y<2$ and $y<2-x$.  Which is just $0<y<2-x$.

For the outer most integral we must select the other variable and integrate over the entire range it can take to fit the three conditions.   Which is just $0<x<2$.

Note: the variable bound to the inner integral cannot appear in the bounds of the outer integral; it does not exist in that scope.

Comment: Could you explain how you got those limits of integration. I don't know where you got the lower 0 limit for the y integral, and why is it just 0 to 2 for the x integral?... why not 0 to 2 - y? @Graham Kemp

Comment: The outer integral bounds cannot include the variable bound in the inner integral.  It does not exist in that scope.

Comment: Could you write out in like numbers how you did that... I'm new to double integrals. This is the first time I have seen them in my stats class, and I haven't taken calc 1 or 2 yet. Thanks again @Graham Kemp